# How to show different profiles on the same asp.net-page

Tags: asp.net

I have a page called profile.aspx that you can access through a meny, when you click on it you come to your own profile (if you are logged in), but then I have created a hyperlink that has another profile's image. When you click on this I want to show this profile on the same page, profile.aspx. But I have no idea how to do this, because if I link to profile.aspx I will for sure come to my own profile.

I've seen in other pages that when you click on a profile the url will be like facebook.com/member1 to seperate all the profiles from each other. Is this a possible solution?

Comment: Are you fetching the data of the profile page using some id or name stored in a session value?

Comment: All the profiles have a unique ID, but I'm not fetching it in a session value, not sure how to. The best would be if it could be like profile.aspx?ID=xxxx, but I'm not sure how to connect that ID in the URL to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are fetching the data for your profile page using a unique id, here is a possible solution you can follow:

As you login, save your unique id in a session variable-

```
Session["myID"]= "your id fetched from database";
```

When you click the hyperlink of another person's image, append the unique Id of that user to the url using query string concept.

```
Response.Redirect("profile.aspx?ID="userID"); //the userID will be the user's uniqueID.
```

When you click the profile page from the menu, append the session value:

```
Response.Redirect("profile.aspx?ID=Session["myID"].toString());
```

Then in the page load of `profile.aspx` you can do like this:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string receivedID = Request.QueryString["ID"].toString();
    if(receivedID == Session["myID"].toString())
    {
      //this is yourself, so fetch your data from DB
    }
    else
    {
      //fetch the data of the receivedID passed in querystring(URL)
    }
}
```